# jqgrid table comlumns crowded

Tags: jqgrid

Please see the image.
[image: jtable]

Not sure why the table doesn't stretch out. I want it stretch out from left to right.
The script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jqgrid_data = [
        {
            id: "1",
            name: "Test 1",
            note: "Note 1",
            amount: "150.00",
            tax: "15.00",
            total: "210.00"
        }, {
            id: "2",
            name: "Test 2",
            note: "Note 2",
            amount: "220.00",
            tax: "22.00",
            total: "320.00"
        }, {
            id: "3",
            name: "Test 3",
            note: "Note 3",
            amount: "40.00",
            tax: "4.00",
            total: "430.00"
        }, {
            id: "4",
            name: "Test 4",
            note: "Note 4",
            amount: "510.00",
            tax: "51.00",
            total: "210.00"
        }, {
            id: "5",
            name: "Test 5",
            note: "Note 5",
            amount: "210.00",
            tax: "21.00",
            total: "320.00"
        }, {
            id: "6",
            name: "Test 6",
            note: "Note 6",
            amount: "70.00",
            tax: "7.00",
            total: "430.00"
        }, {
            id: "7",
            name: "Test 7",
            note: "Note 7",
            amount: "80.00",
            tax: "10.00",
            total: "210.00"
        }, {
            id: "8",
            name: "Test 8",
            note: "Note 8",
            amount: "300.00",
            tax: "10.00",
            total: "320.00"
        }, {
            id: "9",
            name: "Test 9",
            note: "Note 9",
            amount: "90.00",
            tax: "10.00",
            total: "430.00"
        }, {
            id: "10",
            name: "Test 10",
            note: "Note 10",
            amount: "200.00",
            tax: "20.00",
            total: "210.00"
        }, {
            id: "11",
            name: "Test 11",
            note: "Note 11",
            amount: "77.00",
            tax: "9.00",
            total: "320.00"
        }, {
            id: "12",
            name: "Test 12",
            note: "Note 12",
            amount: "56.00",
            tax: "8.00",
            total: "430.00"
        }, {
            id: "13",
            name: "Test 13",
            note: "Note 13",
            amount: "554.00",
            tax: "10.00",
            total: "210.00"
        }, {
            id: "14",
            name: "Test 14",
            note: "Note 14",
            amount: "265.00",
            tax: "2.00",
            total: "320.00"
        }, {
            id: "15",
            name: "Test 15",
            note: "Note 15",
            amount: "765.00",
            tax: "3.00",
            total: "430.00"
        }, {
            id: "16",
            name: "Test 16",
            note: "Note 16",
            amount: "89.00",
            tax: "1.00",
            total: "210.00"
        }, {
            id: "17",
            name: "Test 17",
            note: "Note 17",
            amount: "99.00",
            tax: "2.00",
            total: "320.00"
        }, {
            id: "18",
            name: "Test 18",
            note: "Note 18",
            amount: "49.00",
            tax: "3.00",
            total: "430.00"
        }
    ];
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(
        function () {
            jQuery("#jqgrid").jqGrid({
                url: API_URL,
                data: jqgrid_data,
                datatype: "local",
                height: '350',
                colNames: ['Actions', 'Inv No', 'Client', 'Amount', 'Tax', 'Total'],
                colModel: [

                { name: 'act', index: 'act', width:80, sortable: false },
                { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 80 },
                { name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 80, editable: true },
                { name: 'amount', index: 'amount', align: "right", width: 80, editable: true },
                { name: 'tax', index: 'tax', align: "right", width: 80, editable: true },
                { name: 'total', index: 'total', align: "right", width: 80, editable: true }
                ],
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                pager: '#pager_jqgrid',
                sortname: 'id',
                toolbarfilter: true,
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: "asc",
                gridComplete: function () {
                    var ids = jQuery("#jqgrid").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
                    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                        var cl = ids[i];
                        be = "<button class='btn btn-xs btn-default btn-quick' title='Edit Row' onclick=\"jQuery('#jqgrid').editRow('" + cl + "');\"><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i></button>";
                        se = "<button class='btn btn-xs btn-default btn-quick' title='Save Row' onclick=\"jQuery('#jqgrid').saveRow('" + cl + "');\"><i class='fa fa-save'></i></button>";
                        ca = "<button class='btn btn-xs btn-default btn-quick' title='Cancel' onclick=\"jQuery('#jqgrid').restoreRow('" + cl + "');\"><i class='fa fa-times'></i></button>";
                        jQuery("#jqgrid").jqGrid('setRowData', ids[i], { act: be + se + ca });
                    }
                },
                editurl: "dummy.html",
                caption: "Vendor Managerment",
                multiselect: true,
                autowidth: true
            });
        });
</script>
<table id="jqgrid"></table>
<div id="pager_jqgrid"></div>
```

It seems that the width of the table is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the code which is similar with:

```
 gridComplete: function() {
        var ids = jQuery("#list").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
        for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            var cl = ids[i];
            de = "<input style='height:22px;width:70px;' type='button' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow('" + cl + "' );' />";               
            jQuery("#list").jqGrid('setRowData', ids[i], { Delete: de });
        }
    }
```

After I removed it, it stretches out.